# Plotly/D3 – Reading data from CSV into separate traces

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, plotly

I am attempting to utilize [Plotly](https://plot.ly/javascript/) (based on D3) to read through a CSV and return data into three separate traces - one for each year, in this case.

This [Pen](http://[Codepen]%20(https://codepen.io/angelop/pen/QOgNzm)) depicts the intended result with the data hardcoded into the JS: ‘sales’ data (y-axis), by car dealership (x-axis) and year (essentially a “grouping” variable).

[Intended Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRfVH.png)

I have researched examples of D3 reading CSV data but am unclear how to read my data into the separate traces by year.

- Plotly example – [reading CSV](http://[Codepen]%20(https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/eNaErL))
- Plotly example - [basic time series](http://[Codepen]%20(https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/NvazKR))

For what it’s worth, here is the [sample data](https://github.com/apodagrosi/datasets/blob/master/PlotlyTest_Summary_SalesByDealerByYear.csv).

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it! 
Thank you!

(I apologize if this is an ‘easy’ question as I am new to JavaScript and have very little Plotly or D3 experience.)

Comment: I apologize my Codepen links did not work. Intended output - https://codepen.io/angelop/pen/QOgNzm. Plotly example – reading CSV (https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/eNaErL). Plotly example – basic time series (https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/NvazKR)

Answer (score 2):

@etienne was able to point me in the right direction with this Pen (https://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/VrzwyP)

JS:

```
var years = ['2014', '2015', '2016']

Plotly.d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apodagrosi/datasets/master/PlotlyTest_Summary_SalesByDealerByYear.csv', (err, rows) => {
  var data = years.map(y => {
    var d = rows.filter(r => r.year === y)

    return {
      type: 'bar',
      name: y,
      x: d.map(r => r.dealer),
      y: d.map(r => r.sales)
    }
  })

  Plotly.newPlot('graph', data)
})
```

HTML:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="graph"></div>
</body>
```

I also utilized '[category order](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#carpet-aaxis-categoryorder)' to order the x-axis values that did not have sales (y-axis) values.